# всплывающие окна

Tags: javascript

нужно сделать выплывающее окно когда пользователь кликнул не туда куда нужно, ошибок может быть несколько, соответственно должны они появляться один над другим и затухать. В том коде который я написал ошибка в том что если кликать слишком быстро к некоторым блокам не применяется fadeOut и они не пропадают

```js
function error(head, messege) {

  number += 1;
  $(".error-container").append('<div class="error-messege error-messege-' + number + '"></div><h2>' + head + '</h2><p>' + messege + '</p></div>');
  $('.error-messege-' + number + '').fadeIn("fast");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.error-messege-' + number + '').fadeOut(5000);
  }, 10000);

};

$("#click").click(function() {
  error("Edit error!", "choose another answer");
});
```

```css
.error-messege {
  width: 336px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1c2942;
  color: #ce4d76;
  padding: 22px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  position: relative;
}
.error-messege h2 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.5pt;
}
.error-messege p {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5pt;
}
.error-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="error-container"></div>
<button id="click">click here</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что Вы используете переменную `number`, которая является глобальной переменной. Если кликать быстро, то значение `number`увеличивается, и при срабатывании `setTimeout` значение `number` уже другое.

Есть два пути решения:

- Сохранять значение `number` в локальную переменную, что бы добиться [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).
- Если нет необходимости в `number`, то создать переменную, в которую сохранится ссылка на ваш элемент с ошибкой.

Живой пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/hp0xrauh/).

```js
//Решение с переменной
function error(head, messege) {

   var $alert = $('<div class="error-messege error-messege"></div><h2>' + head + '</h2><p>' + messege + '</p></div>');
  $(".error-container").append($alert);
  $alert.fadeIn("fast");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $alert.fadeOut(1000);
  }, 1000);

};
//Решение с closure
function error2(head, messege) {

   number += 1;
   var currentNumber = number;
  $(".error-container").append('<div class="error-messege error-messege-' + currentNumber + '"></div><h2>' + head + '</h2><p>' + messege + '</p></div>');
  $('.error-messege-' + currentNumber + '').fadeIn("fast");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.error-messege-' + currentNumber + '').fadeOut(1000);
  }, 1000);

};
number = 0;
$("#click").click(function() {
  error("Edit error!", "choose another answer");
});
$("#click2").click(function() {
  error2("Edit error!", "choose another answer 2");
});
```

```css
.error-messege {
  width: 336px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1c2942;
  color: #ce4d76;
  padding: 22px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.error-messege h2 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.5pt;
}

.error-messege p {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5pt;
}

.error-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="error-container"></div>
  <button id="click">click here</button>
  <button id="click2">click here 2</button>
</div>
```